# TypeError: CaptureThumbnail error TypeError: a.getContext(...).drawWindow is not a function / html video tag is not working in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an error when I'm using the video tag in React JS. When I'm using my component in my homepage I get an error, Here's my code:

interface WatchOnTvMobileProps { tvVideo: boolean title: string text: string video: string image: string }

export const WatchOnTvMobile = ({tvVideo,title, text, video, image}:WatchOnTvMobileProps) => {

return ( <div className={tvVideo ? "bg-black py-[56px] sm:py-[72px]": "borderSection bg-black py-[56px] sm:py-[72px]" }> <div className={tvVideo ? "px-[24px] text-[white] text-center justify-center md:flex md:max-w-[calc(100%-4rem)] md:mx-[auto] md:items-center md:text-left md:p-0 lg:max-w-[calc(83.33333333333334%-6rem)] xxl:max-w-[calc(66.66666666666666%-6rem)]": "px-[24px] text-[white] text-center justify-center md:flex md:flex-row-reverse md:max-w-[calc(100%-4rem)] md:mx-[auto] md:items-center md:text-left md:p-0 lg:max-w-[calc(83.33333333333334%-6rem)] xxl:max-w-[calc(66.66666666666666%-6rem)]" }> {title} {text}

{ tvVideo ? your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest to upgrade your browser : your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest to upgrade your browser
} ) }
I get this error in the console: VM2030 pagedata-script.js:1 CaptureThumbnail error TypeError: a.getContext(...).drawWindow is not a function

Do you have any idea?

I try to use the video tag without an error in the console